# anaconda2 can not find GOMP_4.0

Tags: python, c, gcc, healpy, libgcc

I am trying to use healpy the python implementation of HEALPiX. I'm on Ubuntu, using anaconda2. 
I pip install healpy==1.9.1 and check with conda list that it is installed, and that it is using the conda pip, not system.
When I 'import healpy' I get:

```
/home/.../anaconda2/lib/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.0' not found (required by /.../healpy/_healpy_sph_transform_lib.so)
```

From what I've found the problem seems to be related to gcc compilers?
I've had this version installed on this computer before, so this seems to be an issue with anaconda finding the right libraries.

I have checked and I have gcc version 4.8.5 installed. I don't know enough about linking anaconda and libraries to make progress, and I can't find much information!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it installing the folllowing packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc-multilib gcc-4.8-multilib g++-multilib g++-4.8-multilib lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 libc6-dev libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev
```